# How to get the value of timeplot chat using dataset multiplied by getHour() in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to get a plot in time chart using the values of a dataset multiplied by getHour().

This is causing an error.

[image]

[image]

Please note, at the start of the model, the value in acceptedCfD dataset is zero. Overtime it increases to an positive value.

Comment: why would you multiply a whole dataset by getHour... this makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question you are asking makes me nervous

First, a dataset is an object equivalent to some sort of collection of x,y values that also has some methods.

so a dataset can contain the time and the value at that time.

When you plot a dataset, you are plotting that, the time and the value to plot at that time, for each point in your collection.

getHour returns the hour of the day from 0 to 11.

so imagine your dataset has

```
time:0, value:1
time:1, value 3
time:2, value 5
```

what does it mean to multiply that with anything?

if you want to multiply each value of that dataset with getHour() you will need to create a function for that, so you would get

```
time:0, value: 1*getHour()
time:1, value: 3*getHour()
time:2, value: 5*getHour()
```

Or maybe you want it the other way around:

```
   time:0*getHour(), value: 1
    time:1*getHour(), value: 3
    time:2*getHour(), value: 5
```

There's definitely something conceptually very wrong in what you are doing

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation sir. After reading your answer, I understood the problem. Instead of getHour() i should be using time(). The goal is to see how much cost and revenue was generated from megawatt per hour generated (electricity).